# Restoring Windows XP PATH variable

Tags: windows-xp, path

I installed an application that screwed my PATH variable. Now I cannot run anything from the command prompt. Is there any way I can restore PATH variable?

Comment: Had the same thing happen to me after I installed Delphi 7 ent. Luckily I'm running Windows 7 and some other fella showed me the way at [another thread](http://superuser.com/questions/265532/how-to-extract-environment-variables-from-system-restore-point-windows-7-64-bit)!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Got the answer [on Experts Exchange](http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Windows/XP/Q_23153052.html). Here is the excerpt:

Start `regedit` and check for the "Path" value in `HKLM\System\ControlSet<xx>\Control\Session Manager\Environment` (replace `<xx>` with all numbered `ControlSet` entries that are present. No need to check `CurrentControlSet`, it's one of the `ControlSetxx` keys, and you won't find anything under there.)

These are the "Last Know Good" configurations; if you're lucky, there's still one left that has a path variable.

If not, the bare minimum required is this:

```
C:\WINNT\system32;C:\WINNT;C:\WINNT\System32\Wbem
```

Comment: Can't view the above solution without providing experts-exchange.com some payment details :(

Comment: Please update your answer with some details of what you found in that link.

Comment: For the record, this also works on Windows 7.

Answer (score 6):

The default environment variables are stored in the registry under following key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
```

Set the path variable to its default value here:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\;C:\Windows\;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem"
```

Answer (score 1):

A system restore should restore the PATH variable.

Answer (score 1):

### Windows XP System Environment Variables

The key is

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
```

The value is

```
Path REG_EXPAND_SZ %SystemRoot%\;%SystemRoot%\system32\;%SystemRoot%\system32\wbem\
```

That's it.