# How to restore the Path environment variable I deleted?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, environment-variables, path

I accidentally deleted the Path environment variable by creating a new one with Path name. How can I restore my old Path environment variable?

Comment: Remember that each Windows console session has its own PATH environment variable, which can be displayed or changed using the PATH command.  But if you close the console and open a new one, the original system PATH will be restored.  I'm not sure if this is the case with an elevated console session.

Comment: I do not have "History Files" activated, nor "system protection enabled", but I found a very simple solution, just look into a proccess details started before this change, as suggested by @dosaki at https://superuser.com/a/1127136/1743317. You will need to download the Proccess Explorer at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

Comment: IF ALL ELSE FAILS: search all disk for files containing string "C:\Windows\system32;" no quotes case insensitive and with ';' at the end. You can use other strings you know were part of the lost PATH. If you are lucky, you will find a *.log or *.dmp file that contains the lost path. This can work when system restore point, reg backup .. is not available and you already restarted PC not knowing the %PATH% is totaled.

Answer (score 82):

I lost my PATH with a program install earlier today, but with all the existing programs already running, it was easy to get it back. If you have a command window open, run:

```
echo %PATH%
```

If you don't, you can look at the environment variables of currently-running programs with [Process Explorer (procexp)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).

Comment: Excellent answer. Saved me from restoring a backup. May I share a potentially not-so-obvious trick of how to open a command window if you don't have one open. If you have a program that has an open dialog (I used Chrome since it was open before I lost the path), hit Ctrl-O to open a website. Navigate to C:\Windows\system32\ and find cmd.exe. Right-click on cmd.exe and click Open. This will bring up a command prompt with the environment variables of the software (chrome in this instance) and you can echo %path% to get your old env variables!

Comment: This partially works as procexp does show the environment but long variables are not displayed completely. Also there's no way to export or something.

Comment: Certain MSI packages can cause this problem - zapping the PATH environment variable. This is a useful trick if that happens to you - as is using System Restore if that is available. If you are on an SOE ([Standard Operating Environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Operating_Environment), or standardized desktops), you could try to copy the PATH variable from another computer - it is better than nothing and might work properly too if the application estate is the same on both computers.

Comment: Great solution, and I love Process Explorer, but as mentioned by others - long parameter are getting cut-out. I really recommend this answer: https://superuser.com/questions/523688/how-to-restore-the-path-environment-variable-i-deleted#answer-1214550

Comment: I do not have "History Files" activated, nor "system protection enabled", but I found a very simple solution, just look into a proccess details started before this change, as suggested by @dosaki at https://superuser.com/a/1127136/1743317. You will need to download the Proccess Explorer at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

Comment: Using echo %PATH% only displays the path that exists right now, it is the same as opening the windows prompt with the env variables. What we need is the erased path, and it won't be displayed using echo %PATH%. This answer is not helpful. Maybe it works if you just erased it but no if it was erased days ago.

Answer (score 24):

I followed the advice in the answer to a related question [here](https://superuser.com/a/265575/74916) and recovered my previous path setting as of this morning using regedit.  Expanding a bit on that answer, here's how I did it. *(Read the linked answer to get the full instructions, I don't provide all the details here.)*

I selected my earliest backup from today (11:43 AM timestamp in 'Today' section)

[image: Example of previous versions of RegBack]

and examined the earliest ControlSet within the <kbd>HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE</kbd>/<kbd>System</kbd> node of that copy of the registry file, ControlSet002:

[image]

and copied out the previous value of my path variable from the key <kbd>Control</kbd>\<kbd>Session Manager</kbd>\<kbd>Environment</kbd>\<kbd>Path</kbd> within that level.

[image]

Your mileage may vary, as I don't know exactly what triggers the backup of the registry.

Comment: Even easier, a note from the old question "Note that for System, depending on how long ago this was, you can just go back into HKLM\(old control set version)\Control\Session Manager\Environment without loading an old hive"

Comment: What is MOLD? When i go to the previous versions of Regback, I see one previous folder, and despite the depth of the linked answer, I still don't know what to do. Also, how did you manage to open the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/System node of any Regback folder?

Comment: Where are those backups stored?

Answer (score 16):

- From the start menu, open *Run* (or press <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).
- Type `regedit`

  - Find `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE folder`
  - Go to the `SYSTEM folder`
  - Go to the `ControlSet002` folder
  - Go to `Control` folder
  - Go to `Session Manager`
  - Go to `Environment` folder
  - Then, inside `Environment` folder, double click `Path`

The previous Path should be there.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The one chosen works for short variables and doesn't allow for copy and paste. Here you can do it as needed.

Comment: It shows the current path. Not the old one.

Comment: it doesnt show me the path at all :(

Comment: The WinAVR installer clobbered my PATH variable instead of appending to it... Worked for me, thanks for the save!

Answer (score 8):

You could do a [system restore.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc)

> To restore your PC using System Restore
>
> Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, and then tap Search.
>   (If you're using a mouse, point to the upper-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer down, and then click Search.) Enter
>   Recovery in the search box, tap or click Settings, and then tap or
>   click Recovery.
>
> Tap or click Open System Restore, and follow the prompts.

Answer (score 5):

"Restoring" from a default set is another option, with the risk of some installed apps complaining until fixed.
 
Background: Happened when launching WLM after a reboot. The only [thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/error-box-msnexe-unable-to-locate-component/aee821fb-2507-489f-9609-f567fd18ad52?auth=1) with information regarding the missing WLDcore.dll suggested a missing `PATH` environment variable.
Before the said reboot, there was an admin PS console open in the [attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27719275/curl-in-power-shell-windows-8-1-a-drive-with-the-name-localhost-does-not-exi/27723225#comment101946472_27723225) to make Curl accept commands. Must have knocked out the `PATH` variable with it somehow.
Fortunately, and unfortunately, Brink's [default PATH values](https://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/368062-path-environment-variable-deleted.html) were copied to
*System Properties\Environment Variables* before accessing the values from **ControlSet001** (no **ControlSet002** here) referred to in other answers in this thread.
So the only option to recover the original values was with the [system restore](https://superuser.com/a/523690/369805) also mentioned in this thread. A good thing is the apps that use `PATH` on this machine document their requirements of it, so easy to repair.
For those who experienced similar, here's Brink's Windows 10 values:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared
```

And his bare minimum for previous OSes:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

Answer (score 0):

I only discovered the problem with the environment variables days after they got ruined by the installation of an outdated app. But I still had a full registry backup. There one can find all the system environment variables as off the date of the backup. These can then be compared with the current situation as per System / Advanced system settings / Environment variables. Depending upon how recent the backup is, and assuming no environment variable changes since then, you are ok. Worst case is that you'll have to reinstall the apps that you had installed after the registry backup and before losing your path data, which is typically less work than a restore. Below I'll explain how this can be done.

1. Open the backup.reg file with Notepad++ (free and excellent editor). Find HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/ControlSet001/Control/Session Manager/Environment. If that does not work try ControlSet002 or higher.
2. Copy paste the hex(2) hash data for the PATH into a new Notepad++ window. Find/replace all ',' (commas w/o the quotes) with ' ' and all '00' with '', and all double spaces '  ' with a single space ' '. You should now be left with "pure hex" without commas or zeros as separator.
3. Open http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.htm . This is a hex to ascii converter. Copy paste the "pure hex" data into the hex window and click convert. You can now see your path data, and copy paste them into Notepad, compare with the current version, and add the missing data. You're back in business!
4. As a bonus you might also want to check on the other environment variables by comparing the data in the Notepad++ backup.reg with the current values. Missing data can be retrieved in the same way as explained above.

Answer (score 0):

> I accidentally deleted the Path environment variable

So did I, and many commands that used to work suddenly produced an error:

```
The term '<command>' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

The other answers to this problem didn't work for me, so

**I had to recover the Path environment variable a little at a time:**

1. From a plain command prompt, not PowerShell, enter `where <command>`, e.g., `where npm`.
2. Enter "environment variables" in Cortana to edit the system environment variables.
3. Under System variables, find the Path variable and click Edit.
4. Add each file path from step 1.
5. Restart your computer.
6. Repeat for each command that produces the error.
7. Enjoy using commands that work. :-)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses and suggestions, which had lead me into the right direction to create this answer.

Here are the steps to recover your previous `PATH` environmental variable contents if you have any application or background process running that has started before your `PATH` had changed:

1. Download Progress Explorer: https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer .
2. Open `progexp.exe`.
3. In the `Process` list, find an application that has been running since before your `PATH` change. Right click the application and select `Properties...`.

[image]

4. In the properties window, click the `Environment` tab. You will see the `PATH` variable that was used to start this application with. If no environmental variables show up for this process, try another process.

[image]

5. Click the `Path` entry in the list and press `ctrl` + `c` to copy their contents.
6. Paste the copied contents in a text editor and remove the initial `Path` part. You now have the lost `PATH` entries that you had lost. WARNING: This obtained `Path` consists of the system `PATH` combined with your user-specific `PATH` (in that order, separated by a `;`). If only one of both `PATH` variables has been lost, you can use the remaining one to determine where the split between system and user paths was.

This method works because environmental variables are cloned into a new environment when a process starts, thus remaining unchanged for the lifetime of that process (unless deliberately changed). So as long as you have a process running that started before an undesired change to `PATH` was made, it is possible to get the pre-changed `PATH` using this method.

Answer (score -1):

I have just retrieved it by doing as follows:
My previous Path settings was still on the dos cmd prompt screen.
So right click on it with your mouse. Take 'Select All'. This copies your screen.
Open Notepad, and paste.
Now highlight the Path definition in notepad, right click and copy.
Go back to dos cmd prompt screen.
right click and paste
This has worked for me so Good Luck!

Comment: This duplicates information [already present in another answer](http://superuser.com/a/798874/461558), and pre-supposes that one happens to have a command prompt already open in this situation.