# I overwrote my environment variable PATH

Tags: windows-8, path, environment-variables

I've accidentally overwritten the environment variable PATH in Windows 8 (64 bit). How can I reset it? I'm scared to shut down the PC before fixing this problem.

Otherwise I might copy it from another PC that has the same OS (or Windows 8.1)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The orginal PATH is:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
```

If you want to recover your previous PATH setting take a look at [Deleted Path environment variable, how to restore?](https://superuser.com/questions/523688/deleted-path-environment-variable-how-to-restore) .

Comment: So if i create a new varibile environmet with what you have written and name it Path I will not have problems to turn off my pc...?

Comment: Oh! Great! i've solved the problem! :) Many thanks

Comment: How did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I restored my system to the version an hour ago, and I got my old path back, what i did was just go to Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Advanced system settings, select System Protection, click System Restore. Now just wait till the system gets restored (without losing any files, which is great), and the Path is restored as well!
Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a great idea if System Restore is enabled. Unfortunately it's disabled by default, but definitely worth giving it a shot.