# I have accidentally deleted all user variables and system variables

Tags: windows-8.1

i tried recovering in many ways but of no use everything failed windows power shell,echo %PATH%,CMD admiinistrator not working gpedit.msn,registory editor,task manager,advanced system settings anything is not working showing an error type or enter correct name.

im using windows 8.1 pro version and 64bitOS X64based processor can anyone please help me in fixing this out :)

Comment: Windows system restore will fix it, pick a restore date before you deleted them, you might have to paste this into you variable screen first  >>  C:\Windows\system32;  >>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restore the Path environment variable I deleted?](https://superuser.com/questions/523688/how-to-restore-the-path-environment-variable-i-deleted)

Answer (score 0):

> I have accidentally deleted all user variables and system variables

1. Can you log in at all?
2. Can you create a new user?  If so make one and see if you can repair the system.
3. If you can log in, try upgrading to Windows 10. If the upgrade can proceed, it will re-write much of the system.
4. If none of the above, boot with a bootable USB Key, recover what data you can and then re-install the operating system.