# Path variables from system restore point, Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows, environment-variables

Reading the answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/265575) I don't understand this 'little button' to right of open.

> 4. Navigate to your C:\Windows\System32\config\RegBack, click the little button to the right of "Open" for "Show Previous Versions"

What is it? there seems to be no such thing.

I replaced my path variables while trying to work with OpenCV/CMake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always right-click any file/folder, open its **Properties** dialog and click on the **Previous Versions** tab:

[image: 1]

- [Previous versions of files: Windows Vista FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Previous-versions-of-files-frequently-asked-questions)
- [Previous versions of files: Windows 7 FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Previous-versions-of-files-frequently-asked-questions)
- [How to Restore Previous Versions of the Registry in Windows 7](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/31136/how-to-restore-previous-versions-of-the-registry-in-windows-7/)

---

As for your specific question regarding "*the little button to the right of **Open** for **Show previous versions***", he was talking about this:

[image: 2]

Took me some time to figure it out as well; the instructions should have been clearer.