# Recover accidentally deleted Path environment variable

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I use a Windows 7 x64. I just accidentally deleted my user path environment variable and was trying to recover it. I'm glad I found what I really need [here](https://superuser.com/questions/265532/how-to-extract-environment-variables-from-system-restore-point-windows-7-64-bit/265575#265575).

But I don't understand what exactly "Navigate to your user folder" (in point #4) means. What is my user folder?

Answer (score 7):

Your user folder is the folder that contains your "personal" folders and files, like "Desktop" and "MyDocuments". You can find your user folder by opening a Command Prompt window and typing:

```
C:\>echo "%userprofile%"
"C:\Users\yourusername"

C:\>
```

Whatever is displayed for you is your user folder: **`"C:\Users\yourusername"`**

---

Here is an easy way to recover the previous **`Path`**, without having to deal with permanently rolling back to a previous **`System Restore Point`**, and without having to use the **`Registry Editor`** (Regedit).

1. Insure that you have saved a current **`System Restore Point`**.
2. (Temporarily) roll back to a previous **`System Restore Point`** that was saved before the **`Path`** variable was deleted.
3. Open a **`Command Prompt`** window.
4. Insure that the **`Path`** variable has your desired value:

   > **`C:\>echo %Path%`**
   >   **`C:\Windows\System32\;C:\Windows\;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem`**
   >
   > **`C:\>`**
5. Save a copy of the **`Path`** variable:

   > **`echo @set "Path=%Path%">"%userprofile%\Desktop\setpath.cmd"`**
6. Restore the **`System Restore Point`** from **`Step 1`**.
7. Using **`Notepad`** or your favorite text editor, open the file:

   > **`"%userprofile%\Desktop\setpath.cmd"`**
8. Select the **`Path`** value and copy it to the **`Clipboard`**.
9. Open the **`Environment Editor`****:**

   **<kbd>Start</kbd> (orb)** **`--> right-click Computer --> Properties --> Advanced system settings --> Advanced-tab -->`** **<kbd>Environment Variables</kbd>**
10. Locate the **`Path`** variable in either the **`User variables`** or **`System variables`** section, according to your needs and click **<kbd>Edit...</kbd>**. Or, if no **`Path`** variable is found, click **<kbd>New...</kbd>** and type **`Path`** into the **`Variable name`** textbox.
11. Paste the **`Path`** value that you copied to the **`Clipboard`** in **`Step 8`**, to the **`Variable value`** textbox.
12. Click **<kbd>OK</kbd>** to save the restored **`Path`** value.
13. Click **<kbd>OK</kbd>** to close the **`Environment Variables`** editor window.
14. Click **<kbd>OK</kbd>** to close the **`System Properties`** window.
15. Close the **`MyComputer-Properties`** window.

You are done. You have retained your current **`System Restore Point`** and restored the deleted **`Path`** variable.

Save a new **`System Restore Point`** which will contain the restored **`Path`** variable.

You can retain the file:

> **`"%userprofile%\Desktop\setpath.cmd"`**

in case you need to restore the **`Path`** variable again in the future.

Answer (score 6):

Found a simple solution at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C1W04pawwqU

1. Open regedit and find key **Path** under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet002\Control\Session Manager\Environment
2. Copy data for **Path** key
3. Goto *Control Panel > System > Advance System Settings > Advance Tab > Environment Variables*
4. **Edit** the **Path** variable under **System Variables** and append value copied in step 2 above
5. Click **Ok** to save.

Comment: my problem is a system path variable, however when i go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE i do not see ControlSet002 under SYSTEM. Any help?

Comment: It works only till you have not refreshed the environment or not restarted pc.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I followed Ajay's answered and noticed that it's for System Variables. Then I found the solution for User Variables.

Open **regedit** and go to the path **HKEY_USERS.Default\Environment** instead, then copy the path you found and paste to 
**Control Panel > System > Advance System Settings > Advance Tab > Environment Variables**

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't restarted yet, you can attempt to solve this in powershell.

per https://superuser.com/a/1486997/603457

- Open PowerShell.

  - `%env = Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Environment"`
  - `%env.path`
  - If this returns the previous value then save a copy of it in notepad (just in case) and replace your local path variable with that.
  - if you want to stick to powershell, you should be able to use `Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Environment" -Name Path -Value %env.path`

If you were trying to do the same for the machine rather than the user environment files replace `HKCU:\` with `HKLM:\`