# Deleted Path environment variable, how to find the older Path?

Tags: windows-7, windows, path, environment-variables, regedit

I saw the other post like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/523688/deleted-path-environment-variable-how-to-restore) and [that](https://superuser.com/questions/265532/how-to-extract-environment-variables-from-system-restore-point-windows-7-64-bit/265575#265575), but i can't solve my problem, I opened regedit and find the previous version of folder user:
[image]
screen, when i select/open it I can see the folder in the version from 2013-08-14 16:53 because this folder I targeting, how I can find the path with this time. When I make select and then I closing the window, In HKEY_local_machine/system/ControlSet001 or 002 I can find last two paths which are these same.

My question is How I can find the enviroment path value from 2013-08-14? Any links will be priceless ?

When I red steps from other answers, I can't find  NTUSER.DAT and select it, also I have problem with select the folder User I can only open it,  for me select =/= open.

Comment: The answer in the second link should work . . .  To find your ntuser.dat, open the Users directory, then the folder for the user name, e.g. `\\localhost\C$\Users\UserName (‎Monday, ‎August ‎12, ‎2013, ‏‎10:50 AM)`

Comment: I started regedit like a admin, but I cant make this files unhidden, because "the media is write protected"

Comment: I propably make a System Restore it will be easier way for me