# My PATH environment variable got lost during an installation this morning Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, environment-variables, path

I noticed that commands weren't working in my command prompt.  I tried rebooting but still the same problem.  Eventually after looking in this forum, I found out that my PATH variable was effectively deleted and the only entry is one directory of the program I was installing. I uninstalled it, but now the PATH variable is empty.  How do I restore the path to an old version from say yesterday?

I tried the methods in [How to restore the Path environment variable I deleted?](https://superuser.com/questions/523688/how-to-restore-the-path-environment-variable-i-deleted) but I have no entry ControlSet002 in Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment

Comment: “How do I restore the path to an old version from say yesterday?” - Does a Restore Point exist?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract environment variables from system restore point, Windows 7 64-bit](https://superuser.com/questions/265532/how-to-extract-environment-variables-from-system-restore-point-windows-7-64-bit)

Comment: @harrymc no unfortunately not.  I did try that before posting, but Microsoft has removed "Restore Previous Versions" and Shadow Explorer just hangs in Win 11.

Comment: @Ramhound, apparently not, I only get an option to Create one.

Comment: If you have another user account on the computer, you can get the PATH from there.

Comment: It looks like the deafult path for W11 is `C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\ ` - or at least that is what I got from copy-and-pasting from a W11 VM I use to evaluate W11. (Remove the single space at the end.)

Comment: @harrymc I don't, but I managed to find some of these path entries from my laptop which pointed to most of the items in Andrew's reply above

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes I picked up most of those from looking at my laptop and selectively copying them across.  Would be great if Microsoft could have helped!