# Restoring PATH in Windows

Tags: windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Restoring Windows XP PATH variable](https://superuser.com/questions/113646/restoring-windows-xp-path-variable)

Upon installing Ruby and Instiki, my PATH got replaced completely with *c:\ruby\bin*.

Obviously, it never occured to me that any installer would do something like that, so I've no backup, nor any idea what was in the old one (but there was quite a bit in there).

***Is there any way of restoring an old PATH variable?***
(ideas given in similar question to this one, produced no results)

Comment: @soandos, you’re right; that is probably their best bet since they had extra stuff and no backups.

Comment: @soandos - Unfortunatelly, I had System Restore turned off ... (otherwise that would've been an answer). Btw, why, despite my note below is this question voted for closing?

Comment: @Rook, yes, this question is a duplicate of the other one. That question is not about using System Restore, it is about checking to see if the Registry happens to have a copy of the old PATH (which it usually will). Of course the faster you check, the better off you’ll be because it might be overwritten (and thus lost) at the boot.

Answer (score 0):

You can [manually change](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) it to the following default value (any customizations you made will have to be appended as well):

```
%systemroot%\System32;%systemroot%;%systemroot%\System32\Wbem;
```

Comment: this doesnt answer his question.

Comment: Not completely, no. However, soandos is right; there is another question that matches the OP’s problem.