# How can I recover the Windows 7 PATH system variable?

Tags: path, restore

I was installing GTK+ and the installer overwrote my path instead of appending to it. This is my developer machine at work, my path was full with all sorts of developer tools. What can I do to get it back? Will System Restore do it?

Windows 7 x64 Professional

EDIT: I came across [this question about restoring it on Windows XP](https://superuser.com/questions/113646/restoring-windows-xp-path-variable) and it turns out it works for Win 7 too. I can't mark my own question as a duplicate or else I would.

Comment: If you did not restart more than 1-3 times it works.

Comment: I haven't restarted in weeks. I'm so lucky I caught this early.

Comment: If its a duplicate question I would just simply delete this question.  If you want to add to the information in the other thread you should mention that the solution works for Windows 7.